# python signal.scipy.welch for complex input returns frequency indices which are not ordered negative to positive

Tags: python, scipy, signals, spectrum

My aim is to plot the PSD of a complex vector **x**.
I calculated the spectrum estimation using scipy.welch (version 1.4.1):

```
f, Px = scipy.signal.welch(**x**, return_onesided=False, detrend=False)
```

and then plotted:

```
plt.plot(f, 10*np.log10(Px),'.-')
plt.show()
```

The PSD was plotted fine, but I noticed an interpolation line from the last sample to the first on the plot. I then checked the frequency indices and noticed that they are ordered from DC(0) to half the sample rate(0.5 in this case) and then from -0.5 to almost zero. This is why the plot has a straight line across from Px(0.5) to Px(-0.5).

Why the returned f vector(and the appropriate Px) is not from -0.5 to 0.5 ?
Can someone suggest a straight forward method? (I'm used to MATLAB and it is much simpler to plot a PSD there...)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think about angles a complex value moves between two samples, it can be from 0 to 360 (this is the order that welch will return), but another way to see for say `200` degrees is that it is a `360-200=160` degrees to the other direction.

Since you are asking ti to bring the two sided spectrum

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.randn(1000)
x = x + np.roll(x, 1) + np.roll(x, -1) # rolling mean
f, p = scipy.signal.welch(x, detrend=False, return_onesided=False)
```

It will give you the positive frequency followed by the negative frequency spectrum. Numpy provides a `fftshift` function to rearrange a fft frequency vector. Check what the frequency (the x axis looks like)

```py
plt.plot(f)
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f))
plt.legend(['welch return', 'fftshifted'])
```

[image]

So if you plot directly you will see the line connecting the last point of the positive frequency spectrum to the first point of the negative frequency spectrum

```py
plt.plot(f, np.log(p))
```

If you reorder both `f` and `p` you see the expected result

```py
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f), np.fft.fftshift(p))
```

[image]

Note that, for real data `welch` will return the same values for the negative part and the positive part.